# How do google bots work for sites that are database driven?

Tags: php, googlebot, mysql

I didn't see this question already asked but I also don't know if this may be called something in particular so my apologies.  While learning SQL and PHP I was curious to know how do bots search a website if there is no physical `.html` files being populated onto the server?  How do bots index the site?